# Quantize character values and represent as numeric

Tags: r

One column (here multiple rows) in the dataset contains:

Kate

Kate

Larry

Larry

Marie

Marie

Marie

Marie

I want to use R to represent Kate as 1, Larry as 2, and Marie as 3. So, the column would look like

1

1

2

2

3

3

3

3

Do we have functions for quantizing non-numeric data in R? Which to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe what you're looking for is a [factor](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/factor.html).
For example:

```
> text <- c('Kate', 'Kate', 'Larry', 'Larry', 'Marie', 'Marie', 'Marie', 'Marie')
> fact <- as.factor(text)
> fact
[1] Kate  Kate  Larry Larry Marie Marie Marie Marie
Levels: Kate Larry Marie
```

Internally R stores this as a vector of integers:

```
> unclass(fact)
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
attr(,"levels")
[1] "Kate"  "Larry" "Marie"
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `factor` and then to `integer`:

```
> column <- c('Kate','Kate','Larry','Larry','Marie','Marie','Marie','Marie')
> as.integer(factor(column))
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
```